# Persist List which Contains Parent Class in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, orm, persistence

I have a class which I want to persist. It contains one list which has a parent class and parent has two children. The list contains both inheritors. I don't know how I can use `@ElementCollection` and `@JoinTable` to persist this class. I know I have to put setters and getters and no-arg constructor but now this is not important, I want to know how to annotate `List<Parent>`. Tables of Child1 and Child2 has foreign key by entityName to name of entity class.

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class entity {
     String name;
     List<Parent> parents;
}
```

and parent class has two inheritor

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@Embeddable
public class Parent {
   String name;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Child1 extends Parent {
   String entityName;
   @Id
   Double firstChildField;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Child2 extends Parent {
   String entityName;
   @Id
   String secondChildField;
}
```